# MS Access 2007 Form to Form data validation (data type: date)

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

I think I have the way forward but require guidance on the best method for what I would like to do:

MS Access 2007 Database

I have 2 tables for which I have created 2 user input forms.

Form 1.
Site location: The field of concern within this form is:
Date site found (using date data type)

Form 2.
Site Detail: The field of concern within the form is:
Work date start (using date data type)

This issue is I am trying to create a form to form validation rule that defines the following:

The work date start must be >= than the date site found.

I have tried various validation rules all of which do not work such as:

[work date start]>=[Date Site Found]

> =[work Location]![Date Site Found]

The one rule I did get to work required both forms to be open but I did not want that.

However is this the solution:

[willir (MIS) post re: Two form validation using <=Dlookup](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=991571)

Or is the best way to write code in a before / after update event ? 
Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to look at the value that's in the table, not a value that's in another form. [DLookup()](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285866/EN-US) lets you look at a value that's in another table.

In your case, the DLookup() itself might look something like this, if your table is named "Site location".

```
DLookup("[Date Site Found]", "[Site Location]", "Your WHERE clause goes here")
```

You access data in SQL databases by specifying a table, column, and key. Your WHERE clause supplies the key. There's no way to tell from your description what that's supposed to look like, but I'll make a guess.

```
'Using a literal number. Only useful for testing.
DLookup("[Date Site Found]", "[Site Location]", "[Site ID] = 32")

'Referring to another control on the same form.
DLookup("[Date Site Found]", "[Site Location]", "[Site ID] = Form![Site ID"])
```

The linked article show several variations of the WHERE clause that each return the same result. *This* kind of WHERE clause doesn't include the word *where*. That trips up a lot of people.

**Using the DLookup**

Your event code should look something like this.  (I think this should be in the [work start date] control's BeforeUpdate event.)

```
Dim date_found as Date
date_found = DLookup("[Date Site Found]", "[Site Location]", "[Site ID] = Form![Site ID"])
If ([work date start] >= date_found) Then
    'Good. Do nothing.
Else
    'Bad [work start date]. Throw the user a dialog box, and cancel this event.
    'Left as an exercise for the OP.
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Dlookup works, added code to the Private Sub BeforeUpdate event. Revised and tailored the above example code to fit my requirements. This method works a lot better than having a really long validation rule that requires both forms to be open. And now I have the ability to format date and date input to my liking.  Cheers